# Jest test full of errors - Econrefused,Teardown + more

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, jestjs

I have been trying to get async tests working for a while and im not getting anywhere, Can anyone see where im going wrong?

index.js file

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const BlogRoutes = require('./controllers/blogRoutes');
let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
const utils = require('./functions/utils')
let mongoUrl = '';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'test') {
  mongoUrl = 'mongodb+srv://teHIDDENt.g3tzi.mongodb.net/test-test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
  PORT = 3001
} else {
  mongoUrl = 'mongodb+srv://teHIDDENst.g3tzi.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
}

mongoose
  .connect(mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .catch((err) => console.log('couldnt connect to mongo', err));



app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/blogs', BlogRoutes);

module.exports = app

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

api.test.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const supertest = require('supertest')
const app = require('../../index')
const api = supertest(app)

test('blogs are returned as json', async () => {
  const response = await api.get('api/blogs').then((data => {
    expect(data[0].author).toBe('dahl')
  }))

})
```

my scripts

```
 "scripts": {
"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --verbose --runInBand",
"server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js"
```

Here are some of the errors i have gotten and what i tried:

1. Port in use - Stopped running the server, changed port
2. Connectionrefused ... Im not sure why, I have tested that the connection was still working in the browser and it was
3. didnt execute 1 second after... Added the config file which didnt fix the error even though thats what the solution in the docs is.
   4)You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down - unsure of what this means.

Can anyone see a flaw in the structure/setup as i believe thats whats at fault here but i cant see why.

Comment: Using `--runInBand` will run all tests on the same instance, so it will create multiple workers causing a possibility to have a port in use error / connection refused since multiple request could be used at the same time. Use a worker count of 1 to resolve this.  Also for your last error it is possible the test is ending while the function is still running. I would look at using some console logs to see if the function is finishing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I forgot to mention i had tried the worker solution already to no avail. Thanks anyway

Comment: Do a cleanup in afterAll, `server.close(); await mongoose.disconnect()`, use it with --runInBand. You need to either not do `listen` in a module you import or expose `server` that `app.listen(...)` returns to do that.